# Can a role have access to records based on a field of the record itself?

Tags: profile, roles, role-hierarchy

Not sure if I made my point in the title, I'll try to explain it a little better.

Let's say I have a role called Reseller. I have two resellers in my org: Reseller A and Reseller B. Now, I want Reseller A to be able to see a record only if such record has the field "Reseller" set to "A" or "No reseller". Same thing with Reseller B.

Can this be achieved with roles and permission sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Apex Sharing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) or try [Sharing Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_about_sharing_rules.htm).
With Sharing rules you can set the level of access to **Read Only** or **Read/Write**

Basically all you need to do is to create a Sharing Rule for the object you need to modified with this logic. On the Sharing Rule creation process enter the field and the criteria. After that give the access level to the profile you want.

For more complex sharing scenarios the Apex Sharing could be your best option. It gives you more flexibility but involves coding.